Volume integral with two gradients
I am working through a book example where they evaluate the following integral as follows.
Note $\phi = \phi(\vec{r})$.
Given $\int_V-\phi^{*}\nabla \cdot D\nabla\phi dV$,
Do integration by parts by choosing:
$$u=-\phi^{*}; \space\space\space\space dv=\nabla \cdot D \nabla \phi$$
$$du=-\nabla \phi^{*}; \space\space\space\space v=D\nabla\phi $$
Then applying the integration by parts formula,
$$\int_V-\phi^{*}\nabla \cdot D\nabla\phi dV = -\phi^{*}D\nabla\phi + \int_V D\nabla\phi\nabla\phi^{*} dV$$
$$ = -\phi^{*}D\nabla\phi + \phi^{*}D\nabla\phi = 0$$
My question is, why/how does $\int_V D\nabla\phi\nabla\phi^{*} dV = \phi^{*}D\nabla\phi$?
EDIT:
$D = D(\vec{r})$
This is the original wording from the book,


Is $D$ constant?

That's not how integration by parts works in higher dimensions. See Green's identities https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities

What is $D$? And writing $du$ and $dv$ makes little sense in the multivariable setting.

The math in the image is nonsense.

The actual proof looks very similar but the "$uv$" terms are replaced by integrals over the boundary of the region of integration using Green's identities

Even for physicists this is egregious nonsense. Integration by parts for a volume integral is based on $\text{div}(\psi \vec F) = \nabla\psi\cdot\vec F + \psi,\text{div}\vec F$. The divergence theorem gives a boundary surface integral.
